# ORACLE - FLATTEN DATA

Tags: oracle, pivot, decode

I am sure that this question has been asked before but possibly not in this way.

Here is the data:

[image]

I need the rows flattened and the end output:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't included what you have tried and that demands a downvote.

Comment: I was thinking about using DECODE with a sub query or PIVOT but honestly I am stuck.

Comment: How will you decide which make/model is number 1, which is number 2, etc.? Once you have ranked them (hint hint) for each user, you can use the rank as part of the pivot.

Comment: Does the order how the make and model displayed matters for you ?

Comment: The order does not matter per se.  I was thinking that row number 1 would be MAKE/MODEL 1 and row number 2 would be MAKE/MODEL 2 and so on.  I will have to play around with row_number and rank, thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already said we exactly can use `row_number` here and then use the `row_number` to `pivot` it,

```
select *
  from
(  
select userid,make,model,
       row_number() over (partition by userid order by make,model) rn
  from table1
)
pivot
(
 max(make) make,max(model) model
 for rn in (1,2,3,4,5)
)
```

**Or**

Using conditional aggregation which many prefers over `PIVOT`

```
select userid
      ,max(case when rn = 1 then make end) make_1
      ,max(case when rn = 1 then model end) model_1
      ,max(case when rn = 2 then make end) make_2
      ,max(case when rn = 2 then model end) model_2
      ,max(case when rn = 3 then make end) make_3
      ,max(case when rn = 3 then model end) model_3
  from
(  
select userid,make,model,
       row_number() over (partition by userid order by make,model) rn
  from table1
)
group by userid;
```

In both cases you can say the disadvantage is hard coding the row numbers but this is how it works or else you may opt for dynamic SQL if necessary.